# Why is form_valid() being executed twice?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to show a Bootstrap Form Modal instead of the usual form in Django. I have written the following code. However, the form_valid() method executes twice when the modal is submitted, thus adding the data twice in the database. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    form_class = CreateTransacionForm
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = '/main/'
    success_message = 'Transaction created'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        ## Do some additional tasks
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))
```

The request looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozshs.jpg)

Comment: How do you know it's being executed twice?

Comment: Because I checked by adding print statements in form_valid() and it is being printed twice

Comment: Is the modal perhaps sending two post requests? You can check by looking at your browser's developer tools/network tab.

Comment: @WillKeeling I checked it too, and all I can see is a single create request

Answer (score 2):

Insert:

if not self.request.is_ajax():

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if not self.request.is_ajax():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        ## Do some additional tasks
        obj.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))
```